# List of packages managed by DKMS

Tags: kernel-modules

How do I get a list of packages (and their versions) managed by DKMS so I can easily add/remove them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe the command you're looking for is `dkms status`. for example:

```
% dkms status
virtualbox, 4.1.18: added
```

On another system that has a lot more DKMS modules installed:

```
% dkms status
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-33-generic-pae, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-34-generic, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-34-generic-pae, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-35-generic, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-35-generic-pae, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-36-generic, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-36-generic-pae, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-37-generic, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-37-generic-pae, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-38-generic, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-38-generic-pae, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-39-generic, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-39-generic-pae, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-40-generic, i686: installed
fglrx, 8.960, 3.2.0-40-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-24-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-24-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-26-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-26-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-27-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-27-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-29-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-29-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-31-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-31-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-32-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-32-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-33-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-33-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-34-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-34-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-35-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-35-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-36-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-36-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-37-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-37-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-38-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-38-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-39-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-39-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-40-generic, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8, 3.2.0-40-generic-pae, i686: installed
```

More info on DKMS is here in it's [man page](http://linux.dell.com/dkms/manpage.html).

Comment: You sure have a lot of kernel versions.

Comment: That's Ubuntu. I do literally no maintenance on it, just apply updates occasionally.  Not my main system, it's my wife's.

Comment: @slm See http://askubuntu.com/q/89710/6969 on how to easily remove old kernels.

Answer (score 6):

Being pedantic, `dkms status` does **not** show you which packages contain the modules mentioned in the output, if *package* in that context refers to package management.

The easiest way to verify that would be to check which package contains the respective `/usr/src/<modulename>-<moduleversion>/dkms.conf` files (for normal modules) or the respective `/var/lib/dkms-binary/<modulename>-<moduleversion>/*dkms.conf` files (for binary-only dkms modules - although I'm not sure where *buntu or other Debian-based distros put binary-only dkms modules by default, so you might need to verify that path on your distro).

For completeness sake, for an rpm-based distro which has `mlocate/slocate` this could be easily queried via e.g. `rpm -qf $(locate dkms.conf)` as that is the easiest way to get the location of all dkms.conf files without knowing where they might be located for that particular distro.

For *buntu or other Debian-based distro it should work the same way,
e.g. `dpkg --search $(locate dkms.conf)` should achieve the same result and show you the packages that installed the dkms modules listed in `dkms status` output.